# filter inside forEach does no work properly when finds double objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, ecmascript-6

I try to get each object of an array and compare it to the objects of another array. If they match, remove the object from the second array.

Strange thing is that if an object is found two times in an array, that object is not filtered.

I want to compare `newdata` to `existing`. If an object of `newdata` has the same id and cat, it will not be in the new array.

`existing` is

```
var existing = [{
    name: "John",
    values_: {
      id: 5,
      cat: true
    }
  },
  {name: "Jake",
    values_: {
      id: 3,
      cat: true
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Alice",
    values_: {
      id: 2,
      cat: false
    }
  }
];
```

`newdata` is

```
var newdata = [{
    name: "Mike",
    properties: {
      id: 1,
      cat: true
    }
  },
  {name: "Jake",
    properties: {
      id: 3,
      cat: true
    }
  },
  {name: "Jake",
    properties: {
      id: 3,
      cat: true
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Alice",
    properties: {
      id: 2,
      cat: false
    }
  }
];
```

and my filter is

```
existing.forEach((existingitem, existingindex, existingfeatures) => {
  newdata2 = newdata.filter(item => (
    existingitem.values_.id != item.properties.id && 
    existingitem.values_.cat != item.properties.cat 

  ));
});

console.log('newdata2  - ',newdata2);
```

The logic thing is for `newdata2` to have only `Mike` . The problem is that I can see `Jake` two times. `Jake` should not be there, its already in `existing`.

If I edit `newdata` like so (no doubles)

```
var newdata = [{
    name: "Mike",
    properties: {
      id: 1,
      cat: true
    }
  },
  {name: "Jake",
    properties: {
      id: 3,
      cat: true
    }
  } ,
  {
    name: "Alice",
    properties: {
      id: 2,
      cat: false
    }
  }
];
```

I still can see `Jake` in `newdata2`. But why?

Please help me fix this. Is it my filter or the way `filter` works? Based on the criteria, I should only get `Mike` at the end. Please advice.

Thank you

```js
    var existing = [{
        name: "John",
        values_: {
          id: 5,
          cat: true
        }
      },
      {name: "Jake",
        values_: {
          id: 3,
          cat: true
        }
      },
      {
        name: "Alice",
        values_: {
          id: 2,
          cat: false
        }
      }
    ]; 

    var newdata = [{
        name: "Mike",
        properties: {
          id: 1,
          cat: true
        }
      },
      {name: "Jake",
        properties: {
          id: 3,
          cat: true
        }
      },
      {name: "Jake",
        properties: {
          id: 3,
          cat: true
        }
      },
      {
        name: "Alice",
        properties: {
          id: 2,
          cat: false
        }
      }
    ];
 

    existing.forEach((existingitem, existingindex, existingfeatures) => {
      newdata2 = newdata.filter(item => (
        existingitem.values_.id != item.properties.id && 
        existingitem.values_.cat != item.properties.cat 
    
      ));
    });
    
    console.log('newdata2  - ',newdata2);
```

Comment: ... think about a `filter` (outer) and `every`/`some` (inner) based approach instead of `forEach` and `filter` - maybe that makes it easier to think about a correct implementation.

Comment: The problem is that you always filter on the original `newdata` array and overwrite the previous result in each iteration. Thus, the result ends up the same as if you only filtered using the last item in `existing`.

Answer (score 2):

... think about a `filter` (outer) and `every` (inner) based approach instead of `forEach` and `filter` - maybe that makes it easier to think about a correct implementation.

```js
var existingItemList = [{ name: "John", values_: { id: 5, cat: true }}, { name: "Jake", values_: { id: 3, cat: true }}, { name: "Alice", values_: { id: 2, cat: false }}];
var newItemList = [{ name: "Mike", properties: { id: 1, cat: true }}, { name: "Jake", properties: { id: 3, cat: true }}, { name: "Jake", properties: { id: 3, cat: true }}, { name: "Alice", properties: { id: 2, cat: false }}];

var itemList = newItemList.filter(function (newItem) {    // filter `newItem` only
  return existingItemList.every(function (existingItem) { // if it does not exist
    return (                                              // in `existingItemList`.
    //(newItem.name !== existingItem.name) &&
      (newItem.properties.id !== existingItem.values_.id)
    );
  });
});

console.log('itemList : ', itemList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***EDIT***

follow up, referring this comment of mine ...

> your comparison condition just does not fit what you are really searching/looking for.

If one still assumes that the OP wants to filter a new item only if it does not already exist in another list that it is going to be compared to ...

... one has to write a matcher function that maps and compares item fields in one and the same time.

This comparator/matcher then has to be used in a way that it will filter only the very new item that does not equal any other already existing item.

This can be achieved by a slight change to the former approach from above ...

```js
function doesExistingItemMatchBoundNewItem(existingItem) {
  var newItem = this;
  return (
       (newItem.properties.id === existingItem.values_.id)
    && (newItem.properties.cat === existingItem.values_.cat)
  );
}

var existingItemList = [{ name: "John", values_: { id: 5, cat: true }}, { name: "Jake", values_: { id: 3, cat: true }}, { name: "Alice", values_: { id: 2, cat: false }}];
var newItemList = [{ name: "Mike", properties: { id: 1, cat: true }}, { name: "Jake", properties: { id: 3, cat: true }}, { name: "Jake", properties: { id: 3, cat: true }}, { name: "Alice", properties: { id: 2, cat: false }}];

var itemList = newItemList.filter(function (newItem) {
  return !existingItemList.some(doesExistingItemMatchBoundNewItem.bind(newItem));
});

console.log('itemList : ', itemList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice thinking, but this stop working if I do `(newItem.properties.id !== existingItem.values_.id) && 
      (newItem.properties.cep !== existingItem.values_.cep)`.

Comment: what is the new property `cep` supposed to be?

Comment: Whooooops! I ment `cat`, not `cep`, but still the problem remains

Comment: your comparison condition just does not fit what you are really searching/looking for.

Comment: but it wont be correct to just check for id only. what if two objects have the same id ,but different cat?

Comment: @codebot ... there is a "follow up" in my original answer that now does address this too.

Comment: Hi again Peter. Thanks for your time. I had a similar idea. How about this `var itemList = newItemList.filter(function (newItem) {    
  return existingItemList.every(function (existingItem) { 
    return !(  
       newItem.properties.id == existingItem.values_.id && 
       newItem.properties.cat == existingItem.values_.cat

    );
  });
});`

It works properly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter the known items.

```js
var existing = [{ name: "John", values_: { id: 5, cat: true } }, { name: "Jake", values_: { id: 3, cat: true } }, { name: "Alice", values_: { id: 2, cat: false } }],
    newdata = [{ name: "Mike", properties: { id: 1, cat: true } }, { name: "Jake", properties: { id: 3, cat: true } }, { name: "Jake", properties: { id: 3, cat: true } }, { name: "Alice", properties: { id: 2, cat: false } }],
    eSet = new Set(existing.map(({ values_: { id, cat } }) => [id, cat].join('|'))),
    result = newdata.filter(({ properties: { id, cat } }) => !eSet.has([id, cat].join('|')));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check it soon and let you know

Comment: If I got it correctly, you use the `map` to convert id and cat to a string `"id|cat"`. Then put all those pairs to a Set. Then you `filter` the newdata by converting the id , cat to `"id|cat"` again and comparing to the Set, using Set's `has`. Nice thinking. But : Why use the | character? What if tomorrow all names have a |? Also why use strings ? Maybe another combination of Set and map can be more future proof? Can I help you somehow come up with something more strong and universal? I will test solutions anyway. Thanks

Comment: @codebot, if you don't like to use | as separator, you could serrialize an array with the values, like JSON([id, cat]). if taken the array dierctly, it works only by taking the same object reference and that is the reason to take a primitive.